# How to control the way input type=date is shown?

Tags: html, date, input

I want to create a field input in html code that will have a date format. I also want for the user to quickly hit a button that set the day for today.

Here is the code:

```
Fecha de asignación: <input type="date" name="date_s" value="" id="date_s"> <button type="button" onclick="today()"> Hoy </button> <br>
```

When the button Hoy is pressed the date is filled with today's data. However the date is shown as mm/dd/yyyy and I want to show it as dd/mm/yyyy. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: There looks like different types of input types for date, but I am not seeing anything on formatting them here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Yes, my research has shown me that apparently you can't control it. It kind of depends on the browser. Chrome, for example, picks the shape according its location. Which sucks form me. I like my chrome in english. However I live in argentina and it is very hardwired that the date is dd/mm/yyyy and not the american mm/dd/yyyy. I opted for a textbox, for now.